# How can I change the subdomain of current link with a Firefox Bookmark?

Tags: windows-xp, firefox, bookmarks

I saw my boss do this a couple minutes ago. Where I work we have a "staging" server and a "production" server. One is for web site development, where the other is for the finished product. I'm constantly switching between the two domains when checking sites. The domains look something like this:
http://www-staging.website.com/
http://www.website.com/

How can I make a bookmark that just switches the current page from www.website.com/ to www-staging.website.com/ and vice versa?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is an addon for it. check : 
https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/64248/

Comment: I tried this adddon, there isn't much support behind it. Reason I say that is because it wouldn't work for me. It would only show one button "Configure DomainSwitch". I went through the code and there something wrong with createToolBar function er something like that. Its called within the init function when it first starts. Thanks for the tip though. Maybe other people will find that it works on their setups.

Comment: Using customize tool bar, add the domain switch button to navigation tool bar. then restart & you could see buttons for the domains you have added. Its caused due to a bug in the initialize function of the addon.

Answer (score 0):

The easiest method I can think of is to create two bookmarks and put them on the favourite bar, then just click on them.

Quick, easy and works well!